# WOL iOS Project

Tags: iphone, ios, wake-on-lan

There are free projects/examples of wol (wake on LAN) for iOS?

I've found this one [openwol][1] but it's old and has no signs of recents updates.

Also I've been digging on it and it's not working as expected, the main purpose of it is wake a computer but it's not working. I've spent some time on it and still no work.

Maybe there are other examples or someone else may join on me and solve/update this code to work?

Comment: That's a pretty general question. You might do better to post specific errors... check if the wake on lan packet is actually being send from the phone, ensure wake on lan is enabled on the machine you're sending it to, check MAC address

Comment: Before posting specific errors, I prefer to ask if there's another free wol project :-)

Comment: Of course my remotes machines are wol enabled, MAC address is correct, I'm using actually some ruby scripts to wol, but I want to use know my iOS device

Comment: Did anyone find a solution to this? I'm trying to add a WOL feature into my app, which currently just shuts down computers. I've tried OpenWOL but it crashes when I try to use the demo project and integrating the relative code into my app does nothing. WOL is working on the machine I'm testing it with as I have existing WOL apps awakening it.

Answer (score 0):

Wake-on-LAN generally doesn't work for machines on wireless networks, as the wireless hardware is typically powered down when the machine is off or asleep -- it's usually only supported for wired Ethernet. As such, wake-on-LAN is unlikely to give acceptable results on an iOS device, as it'll only work for some specific network configurations (i.e, networks where the wireless segment is bridged to a wired segment that the target system is connected to).

Comment: Those machines are currenty wol correctly from LAN and from WiFi. I've downloaded a free iOS wol app that correcty wake up my machines using Wifi, but I would prefer to use my own App and do some practices with it

Comment: To duskwuff: I don't want to wake my iPhone, I want to wake computers that are wired with ethernet cable, from my iPhone, sending the magic packet